# I have problems with my table of contents, how remove the words “section” “Doc-Start” “subsection” from the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have just finished typing a report. My problem is how remove that words “section” “Doc-Start” “subsection” from the table of contents. I have tried my best to do that but I failed.

I have this code inside my report:

`\begin{document}
\newpage
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{contenido.pdf}​
\textcolor{white}{.} ​
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ }​
\tableofcontents

\section*{}%​
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1. Caracterización de la población estudiantil que presenta el módulo}%​

\subsection*{}%​
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Número de Evaluados en el Examen Saber Pro, a nivel nacional y para los municipios con mayor número de evaluados}%​`

[image: That is the problem, i dont want to have the words "section" or "subsection" and be organized]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I bet you have some errors in the log-file, since these words should not be in the pdf. Can you show a complete but minimal working example?

Comment: Do you want all sections and subsections unnumbered?

Comment: Something in your preamble is conflicting with hyperref's (re)definition of \contentsline.